# "Channel shutdown: connection error"

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, load-balancing, spring-amqp

I've set up on AWS a RabbitMQ cluster with two nodes, and enabled HA as described [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html). Then, I set up an Elastic Load Balancer mapping `5672` to the instances' `5672` port, with a periodic health check to the instances' `15672` port (the HTTP management port). Then, I started two listeners (one in each node), each one with 4 consumers, and pointed `spring.rabbitmq.host` at the load balancer's DNS. However, I'm periodically getting the following errors:

```
[E] [2015-03-14 23:13:23,890] [pool-4-thread-9         ] [CachingConnectionFactory        ] [                                    ] Channel shutdown: connection error
[E] [2015-03-14 23:13:23,891] [pool-4-thread-9         ] [CachingConnectionFactory        ] [                                    ] Channel shutdown: connection error
[E] [2015-03-14 23:13:23,891] [pool-4-thread-9         ] [CachingConnectionFactory        ] [                                    ] Channel shutdown: connection error
[E] [2015-03-14 23:13:23,891] [pool-4-thread-9         ] [CachingConnectionFactory        ] [                                    ] Channel shutdown: connection error
[W] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,758] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-5] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:717) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:707) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:565) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    ... 1 more
[I] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,761] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-5] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Restarting Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-H-1ed6xO3GL7qW58bkLUZA]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://qube@10.100.43.76:5672qube,1), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[W] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,762] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-8] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:717) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:707) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:565) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    ... 1 more
[I] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,762] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-8] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Restarting Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-nJAmieDx-kSuxl9arsXiww]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://qube@10.100.43.76:5672qube,2), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[W] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,767] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-7] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:717) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:707) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:565) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    ... 1 more
[I] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,768] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-7] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Restarting Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-PAQvN8P57_9oiElyqYRJWw]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://qube@10.100.43.76:5672qube,3), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
[W] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,768] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-6] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:717) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:707) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:565) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_40]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:290) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:534) ~[amqp-client-3.4.2.jar!/:?]
    ... 1 more
[I] [2015-03-14 23:13:24,769] [impleAsyncTaskExecutor-6] [SimpleMessageListenerContainer  ] [                                    ] Restarting Consumer: tags=[[amq.ctag-w6apIlL78ViAnTOzx2Qejg]], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://qube@10.100.43.76:5672qube,4), acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
```

This does not happen if I point each consumer directly at one node (without using the load balancer). What can be causing this behaviout? How can I circumvent this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pinging the admin port will do nothing to keep the amqp connection(s) alive.

You need to configure heartbeats to a low enough value to prevent the load balancer from dropping an "idle" connection.

It looks like you might be using Spring Boot (based on the property name) and it doesn't currently expose `requestedHeartbeats` as a property; you will need to override the boot factory by wiring up your own `rabbitConnectionFactory` bean with the underlying rabbitmq connection factory heartbeat settings. See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/amqp.html#connection-factory) for details.

That said, there is no benefit gained from using a load balancer with Spring AMQP because it uses a single long-lived connection. Consider configuring your two instances in the `addresses` property instead and it will fail over to the second instance if the first is not available.

Comment: Sounds like that was indeed the problem. Many thanks! I understand you point about load balancing, but it is more convenient for me to define instances externally (dynamically) instead of doing it on properties. Being that there is no benefit, is there anything that can go wrong by using a load balancer instead?

Comment: No. It won't hurt as long as you have the heartbeats set up ok.